# Joomla Mootools file getting truncated

Tags: apache, joomla, wamp

I am trying to run Joomla on my local machine. I have installed wamp 2.0 and everything installed ok with it and I managed to see it running. I have now come to install Joomla 1.5.18 but I am having a problem with the mootools file on the installation wizard.

When running through the installation process in FireFox with firebug turned on I get errors about the mootools file missing a }. When I view the file through windows explorer it is complete and everything is fine with it but when I click on the error in firebug to see the error the file is truncated which I assume is why it is not working and complaining about a missing }. To test the file I created a test page which pulls in the same mootools file and this works fine (running locally and not through Joomla ).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? I think it must be a problem with wamp as like I said the file is fine and runs ok if I run it from the file system, however I know nothing about servers so this is a guess. Maybe a limit on the size of a file which can be returned as the mootools file is around 7000 characters long.

I have tried un-installing both Joomla and Wamp but none this has not worked and I still get the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just curious, have you tried installing a newer version of Joomla?  1.5.8 is a little bit old and you may have better luck using something a version or two newer.  Alternately speaking, if you're not a big fan of installing WAMP and then manually installing Joomla, you can use a Bitnami Joomla stack.  Basically, Bitnami installs Apache, mySQL, PHP, and Joomla all in one quick and easy install.

I hope that some of this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry I got it wrong above its 1.5.18 I'm installing which as far as I can tell is the latest version.  I'm not fussed about what I install so I'll definitly try Bitnami and get back if it works. Once again thanks for the advice.

Comment: Not a problem, let us know how this works out for you!

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your problem is not with the Mootools package but with your template or modules that are loaded in. Can you turn off all of your modules and reenable them one by one until you see the error again?

Comment: I'm new to Joomla so not sure how to do this.  However I have not even started my own site yest and am still trying to run through the installation process for Joomla. Therefor I don't think there should be anything wrong with the code or they wouldn't have released it and thats why I think it is an apache problem serving the file.